# How to resolve tomcat Failed with result exit-code issue in ubuntu server?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tomcat, server

when I check my tomcat status it occur error. How to resolve this issue in ubuntu server?

> sudo systemctl status tomcat

```
tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-03-22 05:53:07 UTC; 1h 32min ago
 Main PID: 20422 (java)
    Tasks: 21
   Memory: 1.0G
      CPU: 36.353s
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
       └─20422 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.m

Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: Stopped Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 startup.sh[20410]: export JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms500m -Xmx1536M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 startup.sh[20410]: Tomcat started.
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Mar 22 06:01:53 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
...skipping...
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-03-22 05:53:07 UTC; 1h 32min ago
 Main PID: 20422 (java)
    Tasks: 21
   Memory: 1.0G
      CPU: 36.353s
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
       └─20422 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.m

Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: Stopped Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 startup.sh[20410]: export JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms500m -Xmx1536M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 startup.sh[20410]: Tomcat started.
Mar 22 05:53:07 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Mar 22 06:01:53 ip-172-31-41-119 systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
```

**apache.service** file

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=root
Group=root
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> ERROR DruidDataSource:2453 - create connection SQLException, url: jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8, errorCode 0, state 08001
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: have a look at catalina.out

Comment: @EugèneAdell, I have add cataline.out file log in my question.

Comment: the error message is easy : impossible to connect to the database. Check if the DB is available, check the connection settings,..

Comment: @EugèneAdell, I have upload war in webapps. its pointing production DB. But I took thw war with `active profile =dev`  in my war.

Comment: we can't help you more than this dude, you have to do your homework ;)

Comment: @EugèneAdell, Thanks Bro.